# R setRefClass accessors

Tags: r, oop, reference-class

I have created a `setRefClass`, I would like to know how you can implement the accessors so that when you create a new instance of this class you can access the fields by using `setXXX`, `getXXX`.
I was thinking of using `.self$accessors(names(.self$fields()))` in initialize method but it doesn`t seem to work.

```
pathRoot <- setRefClass(
    Class = "pathRoot",
    fields = list(
            # basic info of path
            W = "character",
            Y = "character",
            H = "character"
            ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automatatically generate getters and setters, just use the `accessors` method:

```
pathRoot$accessors(c("W", "Y", "H"))
```

**Example**

```
p = pathRoot$new(W="A",Y="B",H="C")
R> p$getY()
[1] "B"
R> p$setW("Hi")
R> p$getW()
[1] "Hi"
```

You can also access the variables via the `$`, e.g.

```
p$W
```

Comment: Is there any way to add it inside the definition of the class?

Comment: I don't think so (but I've never really thought about it). I usually define the class and just add the `accessors` line underneath it.

Comment: ok, i will go for the line underneath but it is not very clean (my opinion). thx for your help